# How to implement Front-Controller design pattern in AspNet Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-middleware, front-controller

Our **Aspnet Core 2.2** app needs to implement the [front-controller design pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) to select an arbitrary controller based on the app's internal logic. We are not as concerned with selecting an action because we intend to be as RESTful as possible with `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc. Here is an example of what we want to do:

> Given a request to http://example.com/DomainObjectX/, one customer's business rules might use the `DomainObjectXController`, but another customer's business rule might provide `CustomDomainObjectXController`. We do not want to redirect the request but simply use a different controller to handle it the same URL.

Can [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-2.2) choose an arbitrary controller? I cannot find any examples where middleware does all the routing or passes the request along to the default route. My [google-fu](https://www.google.com/search?pws=0&gl=us&ei=5APcXJ3ILe6pgge1yJ8I&q=aspnet%20core%20middleware%20to%20select%20arbitrary%20controller&oq=aspnet%20core%20middleware%20to%20select%20arbitrary%20controller) does not get me there.

Or should we use the [application/controller model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to select an a controller based on our app's business rules? Can someone point to an example that does that?

Or should we implement our own [`MatcherPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.matcherpolicy?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.MatcherPolicy);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.2)? I have not seen any examples that do this.

Any and others would probably work, but I'm not sure how/when to specify the arbitrary controller. So many things to learn ...

Comment: I don't think this is the pattern you're actually looking for. It's very low-level, and more of a framework concern. As a point of fact this is pretty much exactly what ASP.NET Core does. There's the entry point, which routes through various middleware, and then eventually lands on a particular controller chosen by the routing framework, and decisions made along the way. For your scenario, I think you'd be better served with a frontend proxy than hacking at the framework.

Comment: look at this repo implement that [NorthwindTraders](https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders) with mediatR

Comment: That pattern is *already* implemented as the routing middleware. What problem are you trying to solve? Patterns don't exist by themselves. They aren't "best practices". They are solutions to *specific* problems in *specific* situationts. That's what `a solution to a problem in a context` means. If you *don't* have a problem, you don't need a pattern

Comment: As for the example, you don't need a different *controller* unless the actions or payloads on that resource changed. Otherwise, you need a way to execute different logic based on the customer. An MVC controller isn't a business process manager

Comment: I asked similar questions about the problem we need to solve. Essentially, this was done in the full .NET Framework using `IHttpControllerActivator` and `DefaultHttpControllerSelector`, and the boss wants to do the same in DotNet Core. The end goal is to have controllers and services implemented in the base-code and be able to load custom packages where controllers and services could be overridden on a per customer basis. So I need to choose the controller in base or extended package. I currently load all controllers as ApplicationParts but need a chance to make the substitution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, code in `CustomDomainObjectXController` might extend or replace the `GET` action but leave the others.